# Finding the coefficient of a specific term in a polynomial without expanding/simplifying?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I'm learning about Polya's Theorem which deals a lot with the coefficients of terms in a polynomial.

In one problem I had the following polynomial, $(b+w)^{16}$, and the problem basically reduces to finding the coefficient of the  $b^3w^{13}$ term when this is expanded. Now the book very briefly explains how to quickly find this, saying that the coefficient is $16\choose{13}$. Could someone explain why this makes sense?

In general, what is a quick and intuitive way to find the coefficient of a $b^xw^y$ term in an expanded polynomial $(b^i+w^i)^n$ without having to expand it out?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: Wow incredibly helpful... didn't know it had a name! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the $b^xw^y$ term, you pick $x$  times to choose the factor $b$ and are left with $y$ times you chose the $w$ term, which says the coefficient is ${x+y \choose x}$